# Twilio Programmable video - Integrating with Web Audio API

Tags: video, webrtc, twilio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the Web Audio API to manipulate the audio streams of remote participants in a Twilio Programmable Video Room.

You can get access to the MediaStreamTrack that corresponds to each Track in the onTrackAdded Handler trivially, by calling track.mediaStreamTrack

However to use it with the Web Audio API - you must have a reference to the [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) so you can call [audioContext.createMediaStreamSourceNode(stream)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource). My understanding is that a MediaStream object can contain many MediaStreamTracks. (making it more akin to the participant object in the Twilio abstraction).

I have found a way around this by using private properties of the room construct that the twilio client provides, but it is very ugly:

```
function trackAdded(track, room) {
// Check if it is an audio node
if (track.kind.toLowerCase() === 'audio') {
    // Find the relevant pc to get the stream from
    var remotePC;
    room.room._signaling._peerConnectionManager._peerConnections.forEach(function(pc) {
        var remoteStream = pc.getRemoteStreams()[0]
        if (remoteStream.getAudioTracks()[0] === track.mediaStreamTrack) {
            // This is the pc we are interested in
            console.log('found PC to connect to audio API');
            remotePC = pc;
        }
    })
    var origin = context.createMediaStreamSource(remotePC.getRemoteStreams()[0]);
    origin.connect(<Chain of filter Nodes>)
}
```

I guess my question is, is there a way to get a reference to a MediaStreamTrack's MediaStream container in JS?

OR

Is there a more Twilio idiomatic way to get a reference to the MediaStream that corresponds to a particular participant?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than listen to the `trackAdded` event on a room, you can listen to [`trackAdded` for each participant](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Participant.html#event:trackAdded). That way you can associate the track and participant easier. You can get hold of each participant as they join a room by listening for the [`participantConnected` event on a room](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Room.html#event:participantConnected).

Once you get the `trackAdded` event, you can use the [`Track` object and get the underlying `MediaStreamTrack` by using the `mediaStreamTrack` property](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Track.html).

Comment: Hi @philnash. My apologies - the trackAdded handler is indeed registered on each participant's trackAdded event. The reason it takes the room argument is so that during the callback I have access to the room so I can access the private property: `room._signaling._peerConnectionManager._peerConnections` . As I mentioned above - the mediaStreamTrack property doesn't help when trying to operate with the Web Audio API. As to call AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource(MediaStream) you need a reference to the MediaStream (which itself has mediaStreamTracks as properties).

Comment: Oh I see, sorry! You could just use the `mediaStreamTrack` to construct a new `MediaStream` object. `var ms = new MediaStream(track.mediaStreamTrack);` And then use that within the WebAudio API.